# Azure cognitive search escape special characters

Tags: odata, azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk

I am trying to query a azure search index which has special chars. I am not getting the intended results with the following query,

```
{
  "search": "*",
  "filter": "search.ismatch('*\\ca-\\*', 'Text')",
  "count": true,
  "top": 10
}
```

Results set,

```
[{
    "Id": "11110",    
    "Author": null,
    "Text": "ca-1000"
},
{
    "Id": "11123",    
    "Author": null,
    "Text": "da-20000"
},{
    "Id": "11136",    
    "Author": null,
    "Text": "ca 900"
}]
```

Expected,

```
[{
    "Id": "11109",    
    "Author": null,
    "Text": "ca-1000"
}]
```

Basically, I want to query the "Text" field of any record that has value "ca-". What am I missing here?

**UPDATE**

[image]

Its also returning with records with just "ca",

Comment: Can you update your question with some sample output you are getting and expected output. Also It will help in reproduce the issue if you can provide index definition and sample data.

Comment: @RishabhM updated. I am not getting anything back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the provided information, the issue might be because of using same `id value` for both document and the later value is being update to same id.

**To solve this try giving different id for each entry.**

You can check the below code snippet:

```py
# Define the index schema
index_schema = {
    "name": index_name,
    "fields": [
        {"name": "id", "type": "Edm.String", "key": True},
        {"name": "Author", "type": "Edm.String", "searchable": True, "filterable": True},
        {"name": "Text", "type": "Edm.String", "searchable": True, "filterable": True},
    ],
}

# Create the index
headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "api-key": api_key,
}
url = f"https://{search_service_name}.search.windows.net/indexes?api-version={api_version}"
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(index_schema))
response.raise_for_status()

# Upload sample data
documents =[{
    "Id": "11108",    
    "Author": None,
    "Text": "ca-1000"
},
{
    "Id": "11109",    
    "Author": None,
    "Text": "da-20000"
}]

upload_data = {"value": documents}
url = f"https://{search_service_name}.search.windows.net/indexes/{index_name}/docs/index?api-version={api_version}"
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(upload_data))
response.raise_for_status()
```

With above setup I was able to get required results:
[image]

Comment: Thanks, The ids is a typo. I created my own dataset for the example. This is not the exact dataset I am using. I will try your solution and see.

Comment: I have an update in the answer. It is also returning records with just "ca".

Comment: @Joshua to fix this issue, either you can do a post processing to filter out result or you can try using the ngramtokenizer with mingram=3 which can help in preventing the output.